# How to change dates to show full range in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have years in ranges like this:

```
2000-2005
2005-2015
1995-2000
```

I am wanting to know how I can show all the years quickly? 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005

Comment: And what have you done to achieve this? This is not a free scripting site. It is a site that helps people who have helped themselves. So this site can help you with your code if you have any issues with your code. Feel free to share your code and we can help you debug your code. But we cannot code anything for you from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

*Assuming there is no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted, then the following formulas should work.*

---

Approaches shown below doesn't use any **volatile functions**, since **volatile functions**(viz. `OFFSET()` & `INDIRECT()` ), it does not just **recalculate** anytime something on the **sheet changes**, it will **recalculate anytime anything on any open excel workbook changes!**

---

• Using `TEXTBEFORE()` & `TEXTAFTER()` --> Works with `MS365` Exclusively.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=LET(α, TEXTAFTER(B2,"-"), φ, TEXTBEFORE(B2,"-"), ARRAYTOTEXT(SEQUENCE(α-φ+1,,φ)))
```

---

The above formula needs to fill down for the rest of the cells, however if one wants to return the output with one single dynamic array formula then one could try the following:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=BYROW(B2:B4,LAMBDA(δ, LET(α, TEXTAFTER(δ,"-"), φ, TEXTBEFORE(δ,"-"), ARRAYTOTEXT(SEQUENCE(α-φ+1,,φ)))))
```

---

Or, Alternative approach works with `Excel 2019`+ onwards as well.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C2</kbd>

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",,LEFT(B2,4)+ROW($AAF$1:INDEX($AF:$AF,RIGHT(B2,4)-LEFT(B2,4)+1))-1)
```

---

Comment: 's ,  Wonderful solution ,,, + 10 ☺

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the version of Excel and how exactly the data looks.
On the screenshot below is an example of how a single range can be transformed.
[image: RangeNo]

Comment: ,, Wonderful Solution + 10 ☺

Answer (score 0):

**These are my submissions:**

Years In Row:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("-",A2)), TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,SEQUENCE(VALUE(RIGHT(A2,4))-VALUE(LEFT(A2,4))+1,1,VALUE(LEFT(A2,4)),1)), "")
```

[image]

---

- Years In column:

  ```
  =LET(startYear, VALUE(LEFT(A2, 4)), endYear, VALUE(MID(A2, FIND("-", A2) + 1, 4)), SEQUENCE(endYear - startYear + 1, 1, startYear, 1))
  ```

[image]

N.B.  *Adjust Cell references as needed.*